# keep animated element visible on mouse over

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I am using this code to get a panel with and image name to slide out below an image:

```
$( ".image-wrapper a" ).on 'mouseenter', ->
    $(this).next('.panel').animate
      bottom: "-40px"
    , 300
    return

  $( ".image-wrapper a" ).on 'mouseleave', ->
    $(this).next('.panel').animate
      bottom: "0px"
    , 300
    return
```

Right now when I mouseover the .panel it will slide back up because of the mouseleave event on the a tag.

How can I keep the panel open on mouseenter of the a tag and when over the panel and maintain the behavior of the mouseleave event?

here's a fidddle

http://jsfiddle.net/d5e40mw8/4/

Comment: Can you write your code in jsfiddle ? What kind of code is that? Coffee ?

Comment: will do. yeah, it's coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:
Coffee Script:

```
$(".image-wrapper img,.panel").mouseenter ->
  $(".panel").stop().animate
    bottom: -40
  , 300
  return

$(".image-wrapper img,.panel").mouseleave ->
  $(".panel").stop().animate
    bottom: 0
  , 300
  return
```

Enter to ".image-wrapper IMG" and ".panel" elements will animate ".panel" (i added .stop() to the animate to evade some animation bugs). If you leave this elements ".panel" will hide again.

Comment: @isea try it again i wrote `mouse enter` instead of `mouseenter`. Now, it is working for me

Comment: one more problem. There are going to be many of these on the page. I'm trying to figure out how to get it to work with multiple .panel

Comment: Add a class with postid wheb you generaré tour pista. class="id-n" where n change forma each post.